# Explanation of Effective Go if statement

Tags: go, godoc

I was reading through the [effective go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) page and I came accross the following.

> Finally, Go has no comma operator and ++ and -- are statements not
>   expressions. Thus if you want to run multiple variables in a for you
>   should use parallel assignment (although that precludes ++ and --).
>
> ```
> // Reverse a
> for i, j := 0, len(a)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
>     a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
> }
> ```

If someone could explain and break down what is going on in this for loop that would be so helpful.

I understand `i, j := 0` declares the variables i and j, but why is there a commar followed by `len(a)-1`. I don't understand that part along with the some other parts in the condition.

Thank you :)

Comment: I'll continue reading the efficient go while I await an answer

Comment: It's _EFFECTIVE_ Go, not _efficient_ Go. Big difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is assigned an initial value of 0, and `j` is assigned `len(a)-1`. `i` will be incremented and `j` will be decremented by one for each loop iteration, indexing the array from both ends simultaneously, and swapping their values.

This example makes use of Go's [ability to assign the values of multiple expressions to multiple Lvalues](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations).

Comment: @Acidic - If this has cleared things up then please mark this as the *answer*

Answer (score 2):

@nothingmuch's analysis is correct, but I do not like this snippet at all. One of the features I like about go is the lack of clever one liners. I feel like this whole snippet would be much more readable if spread out a little further:

```
i := 0
j := len(a) - 1
for i < j {
    a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
    i++
    j--
}
```

Comment: Another great way to look at it. I agree with how the lack of one liner codes is a plus to the language.